# Error handling in RESTful WCF service in IIS 7.5 with .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a REST WCF web service (.NET 3.5, not using REST Starter Kit) I'd like to create a custom error handler for. It's running as a .svc file in a web application through IIS 7.5. **EDIT:** Probably also worth mentioning; it's running over HTTPS.

The main service class in the .svc.cs file:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/units/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), OperationContract]
    public Unit GetUnit(string id) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="WebReservationService.Service">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebReservationService.Service"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <connectionStrings configSource="WebSettingsConnectionStrings.config"/>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="AuthModule" type="WebReservationService.AuthModule"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings configSource="WebClientAuthentication.config"/>
</configuration>
```

I tried to create an IErrorHandler class and attempted to use that through web.config but wasn't able to get it to trigger. Also tried to catch errors through an IHttpModule Error handler, but that doesn't trigger either. Currently I'm catching errors manually in each WebGet/WebInvoke but that doesn't catch serialization errors or unhandled URIs and the like, not to mention it adds needless clutter to the code.

I know there's something obvious I'm missing, but the answers I've come across don't seem to be usable for my configuration. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Just tried using a custom WebServiceHostFactory to apply a custom WebHttpBehavior. The factory and behavior are both run and the error handler is being created fine - HandleError and ProvideFault are just never being called:

```cs
public class ServiceFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
{
    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = CreateServiceHost(typeof(Service), baseAddresses);
        host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new ServiceBehavior());
        return host;
    }

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}

public class ServiceBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override void AddServerErrorHandlers(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Clear();
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ServiceErrorHandler());
    }
}

public class ServiceErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312652/errors-and-restful-wcf/9353713#9353713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I needed to make a custom ServiceHost and add the error handler in that ServiceHost's OnOpening method. Also had to take the service out of my web.config.

```cs
public class ServiceFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = new RestServiceHost(typeof(Service), baseAddresses);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new WebHttpBinding(), baseAddresses[0]);
        return host;
    }
}

public class RestServiceHost : WebServiceHost
{
    public RestServiceHost() : base() { }
    public RestServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses) : base(serviceType, baseAddresses) { }

    protected override void OnOpening()
    {
        base.OnOpening();

        foreach (var endpoint in base.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            if (endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehavior>() == null)
            {
                endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceBehavior());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ServiceBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override void AddServerErrorHandlers(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Clear();
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ServiceErrorHandler());
    }
}

public class ServiceErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    {
        Utils.HandleException(error, true);
    }
}
```