# Errors and Restful WCF

Tags: wcf

Hi I'm creating a Restful WCF web services that serves up JSON and XML. I believe with wcf 4 you can specify an error object which will return a detailed error to the client in JSON. Is there any way of completely overriding this and return text and therefore have complete control over the format of the error?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have. 
You can create custom error handler and do what you feel like.

See the attached code (just change the JsonErrorDetails class as needed).

**That's the custom error handler:**

```
public class JsonErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        // Yes, we handled this exception...
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // Create message
        var jsonError = new JsonErrorDetails { Message = error.Message, ExceptionType = error.GetType().FullName };
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, "", jsonError,
                                      new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonErrorDetails)));

        // Tell WCF to use JSON encoding rather than default XML
        var wbf = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
        fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, wbf);

        // Modify response
        var rmp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty
                      {
                          StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                          StatusDescription = "Bad Request",
                      };
        rmp.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, rmp);
    }
}
```

**That's an extended service behavior to inject the error handler:**

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is a custom implementation of the WebHttpBehavior. 
/// The main of this class is to handle exception and to serialize those as requests that will be understood by the web application.
/// </summary>
public class ExtendedWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override void AddServerErrorHandlers(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        // clear default erro handlers.
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Clear();

        // add our own error handler.
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new JsonErrorHandler());
        //BehaviorExtensionElement
    }
}
```

**That's a custom binding so you'll be able to configure it in the web.config**

```
/// <summary>
/// Enables the ExtendedWebHttpBehavior for an endpoint through configuration.
/// Note: Since the ExtendedWebHttpBehavior is derived of the WebHttpBehavior we wanted to have the exact same configuration.  
/// However during the coding we've relized that the WebHttpElement is sealed so we've grabbed its code using reflector and
/// modified it to our needs.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ExtendedWebHttpElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    private ConfigurationPropertyCollection properties;
    /// <summary>Gets or sets a value that indicates whether help is enabled.</summary>
    /// <returns>true if help is enabled; otherwise, false. </returns>
    [ConfigurationProperty("helpEnabled")]
    public bool HelpEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)base["helpEnabled"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["helpEnabled"] = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>Gets and sets the default message body style.</summary>
    /// <returns>One of the values defined in the <see cref="T:System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle" /> enumeration.</returns>
    [ConfigurationProperty("defaultBodyStyle")]
    public WebMessageBodyStyle DefaultBodyStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return (WebMessageBodyStyle)base["defaultBodyStyle"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["defaultBodyStyle"] = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>Gets and sets the default outgoing response format.</summary>
    /// <returns>One of the values defined in the <see cref="T:System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat" /> enumeration.</returns>
    [ConfigurationProperty("defaultOutgoingResponseFormat")]
    public WebMessageFormat DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return (WebMessageFormat)base["defaultOutgoingResponseFormat"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["defaultOutgoingResponseFormat"] = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the message format can be automatically selected.</summary>
    /// <returns>true if the message format can be automatically selected; otherwise, false. </returns>
    [ConfigurationProperty("automaticFormatSelectionEnabled")]
    public bool AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)base["automaticFormatSelectionEnabled"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["automaticFormatSelectionEnabled"] = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the flag that specifies whether a FaultException is generated when an internal server error (HTTP status code: 500) occurs.</summary>
    /// <returns>Returns true if the flag is enabled; otherwise returns false.</returns>
    [ConfigurationProperty("faultExceptionEnabled")]
    public bool FaultExceptionEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)base["faultExceptionEnabled"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["faultExceptionEnabled"] = value;
        }
    }
    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.properties == null)
            {
                this.properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection
                {
                    new ConfigurationProperty("helpEnabled", typeof(bool), false, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None), 
                    new ConfigurationProperty("defaultBodyStyle", typeof(WebMessageBodyStyle), WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None), 
                    new ConfigurationProperty("defaultOutgoingResponseFormat", typeof(WebMessageFormat), WebMessageFormat.Xml, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None), 
                    new ConfigurationProperty("automaticFormatSelectionEnabled", typeof(bool), false, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None), 
                    new ConfigurationProperty("faultExceptionEnabled", typeof(bool), false, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None)
                };
            }
            return this.properties;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>Gets the type of the behavior enabled by this configuration element.</summary>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="T:System.Type" /> for the behavior enabled with the configuration element: <see cref="T:System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior" />.</returns>
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(ExtendedWebHttpBehavior);
        }
    }
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new ExtendedWebHttpBehavior
        {
            HelpEnabled = this.HelpEnabled,
            DefaultBodyStyle = this.DefaultBodyStyle,
            DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = this.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat,
            AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = this.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled,
            FaultExceptionEnabled = this.FaultExceptionEnabled
        };
    }
}
```

**That's the web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="regularService" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
      <extendedWebHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="extendedWebHttp" type="MyNamespace.ExtendedWebHttpElement, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyWebService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="regularService"
      contract="IMyWebService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

**Note:** The behavior extension should be in one line EXACTLY as is (there's a bug in WCF).

**That's my client side (part of our custom proxy)**

```
 public void Invoke<T>(string action, object prms, JsAction<T> successCallback, JsAction<WebServiceException> errorCallback = null, JsBoolean webGet = null)
    {
        Execute(new WebServiceRequest { Action = action, Parameters = prms, UseGetMethod = webGet },
            t =>
            {
                successCallback(t.As<T>());
            },
            (req, message, err)=>
            {
                if (req.status == 400) //Bad request - that's what we've specified in the WCF error handler.
                {
                    var details = JSON.parse(req.responseText).As<JsonErrorDetails>();
                    var ex = new WebServiceException()
                    {
                        Message = details.Message,
                        StackTrace = details.StackTrace,
                        Type = details.ExceptionType
                    };

                    errorCallback(ex);
                }
            });
    }
```